# Discord.js - How do you log username, discriminator & avatar changes?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm setting up logging with my Discord.js bot and I've tried to log username/discriminator/avatar changes with the guildMemberUpdate event, but nothing happens. I then had a look around on the internet a bit and apparently you need to set up a database in order to be able to store these changes and log them. Is this correct? If so, could someone clarify this?

Thanks

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`userUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-userUpdate) event instead

```js
client.on('userUpdate', (oldUser, newUser) => {
  if (oldUser.avatar !== newUser.avatar) console.log(`${newUser.username}'s avatar changed!`)
  if (oldUser.username !== newUser.username) console.log(`${oldUser.username}'s new username is ${newUser.username}!`)
  if (oldUser.discriminator !== newUser.discriminator) console.log(`${newUser.username}'s new discriminator is ${newUser.discriminator}!`)
})
```

Comment: Ohhhh okay, they hid it at the bottom of the docs! Thanks very much :)